# C++ simple asynchronous server library

Tags: c++, asynchronous

Is there any c++ library that helps implementing a simple and efficient HTTP server able to handle a very large number of concurrent connections? I'd need something very similar to python's [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), but for c++

Thanks

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175507/c-c-web-server-library

Answer (score 4):

There is boost ASIO library.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably a bit late to this party, but [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) comes with an [included HTTP server](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/doxygen-2.0.1/http_8h.html).